# Xcode 8.3 get data from php and json

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make a small program, that send a username to a web data base. and get the name, status, point of the user.
i have fund out how to send the username, and get the json output.
it look like this: {"name":"gert","status":"0","point":"20"}
and this is my php code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
ob_start();
session_start();
mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Unable to select database");

$qrcode = $_POST['username'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qrcode WHERE qrcode = '$qrcode' ");
$pic_name = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$myObj = new \stdClass();
                $myObj->name = $pic_name['name'];
                $myObj->status = $pic_name['status'];
                $myObj->point = $pic_name['point'];

                $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

                echo $myJSON;

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

and this is my swift code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let url_to_request:String = "http://www.hholm.dk/time_app/gertqrcode.php"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    download_request()

      }

func download_request()
{
    let url:URL = URL(string: url_to_request)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = "username=200"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


    let task = session.downloadTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        location, response, error) in


        let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOf: location!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

        guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        print(urlContents)


    }) 

    task.resume()

}


}
```

and now i have to extract the json, (i think its called)
I would like to have the name, status and point, as some ting i can use i the rest of the program.

Comment: I would suggest looking at swiftyJSON https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON if you just need JSON mapping. AlamoFire with ObjectMapper is great if you are making a lot of request to the server.

Answer (score 0):

try it.
If you have any questions let me know, I hope I have helped!

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class getJSON: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate
{
    //properties
    var data : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func downloadItems(user:String)
    {
        let url = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.102:8888/test/test.php")! as URL)
        url.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(user)"
        url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print(url.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))

        var session: URLSession!
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url as URLRequest)

        task.resume()

    }



    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, dataTask: URLSessionDataTask, didReceive data: Data)
    {
        self.data.append(data as Data);
    }



    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?)
    {
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Not Found", error ??)

        }
        else
        {
            print("Ok")
            self.parseJSON()
        }

    }


    func parseJSON()
    {

        var jsonResult: NSArray = NSArray()

        do
        {
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

            print("jsonResult.count",jsonResult.count)
        }
        catch let error as NSError
        {
            print("jsonResult: ", error)
        }


        var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
        var contador = 0
        for i in (0..<jsonResult.count)
        {
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            if let nameUser = jsonElement["name"] as? String,
                let pointUser = jsonElement["point"] as? String,
                let statusUser = jsonElement["status"] as? String
            {
                print("Name: ", nameUser)
                print("Status: ", statusUser)
                print("Point: ", pointUser)
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Try this in your php, I'm showing you how I made it work for me, it will need to change as you wish, I'm passing this code as an example.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
ob_start();
session_start();
mysql_connect("host","username","password");
mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Unable to select database");

$qrcode = $_POST['username'];


        $query="SELECT name,status,point FROM qrcode WHERE qrcode = '$qrcode'";

        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        $data = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
             $data[] = $row;
        }

        //echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

        echo json_encode($data);        




ob_end_flush();
?>
```

In your viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Status: ",getStatusUSer)
    }

    @IBAction func get(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let userName = "charles"
        let getUser  = getJSON()
        getUser.downloadItems(user:userName)
    }

    //Your Code...
}
```

Comment: Hi cwilliams and thanks, but there is a error, this it the output:

()
Ok
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x10a707288) to 'NSArray' (0x10a706e28).
{"name":"gert","status":"0","point":"20"}
(lldb) 

it's it the:

jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: self.data as Data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

Comment: Hi, include php in my answer as an example, see if it works for you.

Comment: Hi cwilliams, thanks this work fine, But how do i get the statusUser to the ViewController

Comment: Within this if add the variable that you want to receive statusUser, for example the test variable.

If let nameUser = jsonElement ["nameUser"] as? String,
                 Let statusUser = jsonElement ["statusUser"] as? String
             {
                        Test = statusUser
             }

Comment: thanks, this i have finde out :-)
But, i have a ViewController and a getJSON file, and i need the statusUser
to be displayed in the ViewController.
and That i don't know how to import the statusUser to the file.

Comment: Crie uma variavel global fora da classe, assim poderá usar ela em qualquer local do seu aplicativo.

import Foundation
import UIKit
var statusUSer = ""
class getJSON: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate
{
      ...
}

Comment: I have finde out how to call the func in the viewController, like this:
let instanceOfUser = getJSON()
 instanceOfUser.downloadItems()
But how do i get the statusUser in to the viewcontroller

Comment: I edited the code above, follow the variable "getStatusUSer" in the code that you will get the logic that I used.

Comment: sorry, but i can't get it to work, its just print "status", and not the getStatusUSer

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do, if you can, try to explain it in more detail.

Comment: this is what i got in my viewcontroller:

`//  ViewController.swift
//  nsurlsession_tutorial

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let getUser  = getJSON()
        getUser.downloadItems()
        
        print("Status: ", getStatusUSer)
      
    }
    
    //Your Code...
}`

Comment: What error do you get when executed? Can you copy or display any xcode console and paste for me to parse?

Comment: if i add a like this :

    '@IBAction func get(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Status: ", getStatusUSer)
    }'
in the viewcontroller, it will print the getStatusUSer,

Comment: Yes, it would print, now it's you to print to different users, be necessary to pass as parameter in the function downloadItems () the status user to get the status; I recommend a respect of functions with parameter passing and returns to get the code for your reality, it is easy, access the link https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Comment: thanks cwilliams, i have try to read the link you send, but i not understand so much, i'm new to xcode, but i ges i have to keep trying

Comment: I edited my code above, see that now the value you assign to the userName variable will be the value fetched in the database, the data being printed on the terminal.
Important note that the downloadItems function now receives the value of the variable userName to query the database.
If you need to save the printed data you can get this data in the parseJSON () function.
If this helps, do not forget to qualify my answer :)